# Como llamar desde un botón en un form un crystal report Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un form con varios botones que llaman diferentes forms en el programa, acabo de crear un Crystal report pero no se como imprimirlo o llamarlo desde ese botón

así lo intenté pero no funciona:

```
private void btnrpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         Creyreport reporte = new Cryreport(); 
         reporte.show();
        }
```

Comment: Las clases son diferentes  Creyreport y Cryreport();, además donde tienes los datos del reporte?

Comment: Tengo los datos en un acces al cual ya le hice la conexión